# C++ Clase Prototipo

Tags: c++, poo, clase

Hola tengo un problema:

```
include <iostream>

using namespace

class varios;

int main()
{
   cuerpo.hola();
   cin.get();
   return 0;
}

class varios
{
   public:
   void hola();
}cuerpo;

void class::hola()
{
   cout<<"Este es un ejemplo";
}
```

Estoy declarando una clase prototipo, pero no se como declarar el objeto para que lo reconozca el main

Comment: si recurro aca es porque no he hallado nada de esto en algun libro o en otra pagina

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No definas variables al final de la declaración de la clase.

Simplemente usa el nombre de la clase como si fuera un tipo estándar:

```
#include <iostream>

class varios
{
   public:
        void hola();
};

void varios::hola()
{
   std::cout<<"Este es un ejemplo";
}

int main()
{
   // Defines una variable de tipo varios
   varios cuerpo;
   cuerpo.hola();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow de recien caigo en cuenta, muchas gracias